# What guidelines should be met for something to be called a webapp

Tags: web-applications

In my mind a webapp is any website that has some complicated features and that's served from the web, but I know there are people who are a lot smarter than me here and they'll point out other features that I'm not noticing. For example:

- If it doesn't have a login system, can I still call it a webapp? (because most webapps end up being user-based).
- Should I think of a CMS as a webapp? and how about the sites that are built with it? probably they're not webapps, right?
- Is Gmail a webapp? I think so.
- Is twitter a webapp? Yes, though the functionality is rather simple.

So what conditions need to be met to call a website a webapp?

P.S. StackExchange's tag system defines web-applications as

> applications that are accessed over the "web", which can mean the
>   Internet, or an internal network (an intranet).

Comment: At what level of complexity does that glob of code you just wrote qualify to be called a "program?"

Comment: @Blrfl Yes, I guess that's what it boils down to, but shouldn't we establish some guidelines. A junior developer might look at their simple code and think their glob of code is pretty awesome and deserves to be called a webapp. A senior developer probably writes more complicated code than found in most webapps. That's why having some rough guidelines is important.

Comment: What benefit would there be in establishing a formal, complexity-based definition of the term?  Given that technology evolves, would that definition have to change every few years?  Would a state-of-the-art "web app" I wrote in 1995 be stripped of its "web app" status, or could I still call it a "1995 web app?"

Answer (score 5):

There is only one requirement - a program running on some server that responds to HTTP requests. All the rest is just hype and vague marketing catch phrases.

In other words, an **application** (program) that runs over the **web** (HTTP).

If this doesn't answer your question, then it doesn't belong in programming Q&A, but in marketing.

Comment: Based on your answer, I guess the question is what makes a website a (program) :) Today's regular websites can offer some complicated functionality, so by this logic, are most websites today considered webapps?

Comment: +1 for calling the marketing department to leverage those strategic synergies.

Comment: @sameold A lot of websites generate output (visible content) simply by reading from local HTML files, wrapping them with an HTTP response and sending them over a socket. This is done automatically by programs such as Apache. Generally, in the world of web hype, a web application is one that dynamically generates content from say, user input, databases and stuff like that. And let's not forget, uses the latest bleeding edge feature-bloated framework, in object-oriented or functional languages, and... the *most* important feature - it *requires* browser plugins. :)

Answer (score 1):

It's somewhat contextual. In general, it's any application that interfaces over the web.

However, if you are talking about a webapp in the context of Java, it is implied that it's an application that, at minimum, conforms to the [Java Servlet Specification](http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr154/index.html). In other contexts, it might have other implications.